# what is object instance?Does it mean creating a copy of class?

Tags: java, oop

When an object instance is created from a class, the class's constructor function is run to create it. This process of creating an object instance from a class is called instantiation — the object instance is instantiated from the class.I am confused with term instance.Does it mean creating a copy of a class?

Comment: creating an instance of a class is creating an object whose type is that class.

Comment: see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: A "class" can be seen as a blueprint, an instance is an object that is created using that blueprint.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an instance of a `class` is creating an object of that class type.

Example

```
class A{}

A a = new A();
```

Type of variable `a` is `A`.